# How to color status bar and navigation bar

Tags: applications, notification-bar, android-versions, accessibility

I really like that my status bar and navigation bar have the same colour with a running software without rooting, because I don't like black navigation bar, is there any way? If it's impossible without rooting, how about through accessibility service?
My smartphone: Huawei Ascend G7- L11
Please reply
Yours truly

Comment: As far as I can remember, there's an app that can change status bar color without root (from Settings->Accessibility permission), but I don't think you can change nav bar's color without rooting.

Comment: Tanks for your answer, what is its name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this app **to set the color of status bar** through *Accessibility Service* :

## **[Color Status Bar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thirstystar.colorstatusbar&hl=en)**

(*Note:* This app runs in background to enable the color.
And, this app will work only on devices running Android 5 or above..)

But to change the color of navigation bar, you need root access.

If your device is rooted, do the following **to change navbar color**:

1. Install Xposed Framework and Xposed Installer app.
2. Install "GravityBox" module (varies for different Android versions) and reboot.
3. Open GravityBox app, goto *Navigation Bar Tweaks*
4. Under *Colors* section, Enable *Navbar Colors* and set your desired color.

Comment: Thanks a lot but my android version is 4.4.4 Kitkat, is there any ship like that or ifs there any other way

Comment: Oh, is your phone rooted? Only then it's possible